# Android runtime error (real device only): SecurityException

Tags: android, android-build

The app works on my Genymotion emulator but fails when running on the real device with this exception on startup:

```
Launching application: <package>/<package>.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "<package>/<package>.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=<package>/.MainActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=<package>.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=<package>/.MainActivity } from null (pid=21943, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10204
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2204)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:494)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:109)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:82)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Waiting for process: <package>
```

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="<package>"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="<package>.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

What's going on?  Why would it be trying to run as a particular user when I'm just using a normal configuration?

Comment: Please paste code from your MainActivity where you are using intent in that activity to get more idea about it

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal, I should have been more clear, my onCreate breakpoint doesn't hit, doesn't look like any breakpoint hits (altho it hits on the virtual machine)

Comment: yeah thats why i am asking for the code of that activity so we can see what is the problem in that activity. You should paste your main activity and its parent activity if there is any

Comment: Why would the code matter if it's not firing?

Comment: that matters becuae the error is in your code or manifest probably thats why it is not even executing a single breakpoint there. Please paste your manifest

Comment: Please check ans below you didn't define MainActivity as launcher activity. Do you have any other Parent activity of main activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change below in you `menifest.xml` file

```
<activity
     android:name="<package>.MainActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Your updated answer fixed it, thank YOU!  also why would the default be broken, I didn't even mess with it?  seems very odd

Comment: @pfrank so you need INTERNET permission ?

Comment: No it was an issue with how the activity was being defined I believe

Answer (score 0):

You should define your activity something like this in manifest

```
       <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/AppTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```